# Tabs showing perfectly on api 14+ but on api <14 they are invisible or weird sized

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, compatibility

I created a 5 tabbed application. On a 4.0+ system all is working and nice looking, but before 4.0 the tabs are weird behavior or really big :/

As you cas see in the images, the 1 is like i want (and how it is on 4.0+), the 2 is too big and when i try to reduce the font, the image etc i got the picture 3, no tabs anymore.

[image: The image]

**My main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@color/Fond_Tab_Select"
   android:id="@+id/linearlayout_titre"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">


    <TabWidget
     android:id="@android:id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:tabStripEnabled="false"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>


   </HorizontalScrollView>

  <FrameLayout
   android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
   android:background="@color/Fond_Tab_Unselected" />

 </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**and the tab_indicator.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

---

If i try to set a textsize = 10 in tab_indicator for the textview, tabs don't show up anymore. Did i missed something ?

**My method to create the tabs :**

```
public View cree_tab(int Titre, int Image) {

  View tb;

  if ( currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ) {

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.text_tab_indicator));
    title.setText(Titre);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(Image);
    tb = tabIndicator;

  } else {

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_froyo, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.text_tab_indicator));
    title.setText(Titre);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(Image);
    tb = tabIndicator;

  }
  return tb;
}
```

Comment: Finally, i **didn't found the solution** with tabhost. I had to **use fragments instead** and to rewrite the whole structure.

Now it's works fine and it's looking the way i wanted :)
[Here is the result](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shoyun.aideshot)